# How Django model field take default value if field is None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create a django model

```
class Apps(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="name")
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="package_name")
```

and **i may or may not receive both (name, package_name)**

my insert query function

```
def func(data):
    try:
       kwargs = dict(name=data.get('name'),
                     package_name=data.get('package_name'))
       app = Apps.objects.get(**kwargs)
    except:
       app = Apps(**kwargs)
       app.save()
    return app
```

**My Problem is**

when `kwargs = {"name" : None, "package_name": "pkg"}` than it take default value as specified in model field corresponding to name (because it is `None` in `kwargs`)

Comment: try `blank = True` parameter in name field

Comment: What value do you want it to use when "name" is `None`? I don't understand why have you set a default value if you don't want it be used?

Comment: if user not send name than we use default , this just an example

Answer (score 2):

Django can't just substitute the default values to a query, you have to help it a bit:

In your model define some constants:

```
class Apps(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_NAME = 'name'
    DEFAULT_PACKAGE_NAME = 'package_name'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=DEFAULT_NAME)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=DEFAULT_PACKAGE_NAME)
```

And then just use them in your code:

```
def func(data):
    kwargs = dict(name=data.get('name', Apps.DEFAULT_NAME),
                  package_name=data.get('package_name', Apps.DEFAULT_PACKAGE_NAME))
    return Apps.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)[0]
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, did the answer solve your problem? If not, please share your solution with us to make this post complete. If yes, consider marking it as accepted, so that the others can rely on it.